# How to remove a symbol from a map

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I am currently creating a map which updates based on users selection and displays 5 location closest to them. This works however when the user changes their selection the map updates and displays the 5 NEW locations as well as the 5 OLD locations.

I am not sure how to remove the old symbols.

public  void displayResults(ArrayList allLocation) {

```
    SymbolManager sm = new SymbolManager(mapView,map,styleMap);

    sm.deleteAll();
    SymList.clear();


        sm.setIconAllowOverlap(true);
        sm.setIconIgnorePlacement(true);

    int count = 1;

    for (LocationDetails a : allLocation
    ) {
        // gets the distance from user to Location
        double LocationLat = Double.parseDouble(a.getLatitude());
        double LocationLng = Double.parseDouble(a.getLongitude());
        float[] disResult = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(lat, lng, LocationLat, LocationLng, disResult);
        results.append(count + ": " + a.getName() + " " + "\n");
        distanceResults.append(Math.round(disResult[0]) + "m" + "\n");

        SymbolOptions symbolOptions = new SymbolOptions()
                .withLatLng(new LatLng(LocationLat, LocationLng))
                .withIconImage("marker-11")
                .withTextField(""+count)
                .withIconColor("black")
                .withIconSize(2.5f);

        SymList.add(symbolOptions);

        count++;
    }

    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(SymList.get(0).getLatLng())
            .include(SymList.get(1).getLatLng())
            .include(SymList.get(2).getLatLng())
            .include(SymList.get(3).getLatLng())
            .include(SymList.get(4).getLatLng())
            .build();

    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBounds, 50), 2000);

    for(SymbolOptions a : SymList){
        sm.create(a);
    }

    SymList.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been using mapbox for 3 months. After hours of research I discovered that on Android the only way to remove a Symbol or any element on the map was to reload all the elements from scratch. Unfortunately, there is currently no method to remove a single element.
So I suggest you create a container class in which to save your items.

Answer (score 1):

If your use case only requires showing about five markers on the map at a time, it might be easier to use native sources and [`SymbolLayer`](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/api/map-sdk/9.0.0/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/style/layers/SymbolLayer.html)s rather than relying on the abstraction provided by the `SymbolManager`.

For example, this [icon updates based on API response Android demo](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/api-response-icon-update/) shows how to add a GeoJSON source and corresponding layer to the map, then update said source to get a different visual result. Basically all of the logic you will need is encapsulated here, but your GeoJSON will be a `FeatureCollection` of multiple (namely, 5) features rather than just one point.

So, you can set up your symbols similarly to how it's done in the linked example:

```
private void initSpaceStationSymbolLayer(@NonNull Style style) {
  style.addImage("space-station-icon-id",
  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(
  this.getResources(), R.drawable.iss));

  style.addSource(new GeoJsonSource("source-id"));

  style.addLayer(new SymbolLayer("layer-id", "source-id").withProperties(
    iconImage("space-station-icon-id"),
    iconIgnorePlacement(true),
    iconAllowOverlap(true),
    iconSize(.7f)
  ));
}
```

, and then update the source's GeoJSON to the new locations closest to the user's position, similar to the `updateMarkerPostion` method:

```
private void updateMarkerPosition(LatLng position) {
  // This method is where we update the marker position once we have new coordinates. First we
  // check if this is the first time we are executing this handler, the best way to  do this is
  // check if marker is null;
  if (map.getStyle() != null) {
    GeoJsonSource spaceStationSource = map.getStyle().getSourceAs("source-id");
    if (spaceStationSource != null) {
      spaceStationSource.setGeoJson(FeatureCollection.fromFeature(
      Feature.fromGeometry(Point.fromLngLat(position.getLongitude(), position.getLatitude()))));
    }
  }

  // Lastly, animate the camera to the new position so the user
  // wont have to search for the marker and then return.
  map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(position));
}
```

A few modifications will need to be made, of course, but this option might be more direct for your implementation specifically.